# Hotkey for moving objects along specific axis changed

Tags: objects, transforms, shortcut

Recently I've been moving objects around, then suddenly when I try to move one of my objects to the left along the X axis (the red line) by clicking it and then pressing the hotkey "X", it turns out to be moving along the "Z" axis (the blue line), and vice-versa (when I click the object and press the "Z" hotkey. it moves along the "X" axis. I already checked my settings, and it appears to be happen only to this file. Can someone help me how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: You have a custom coordinate system called "FRAME1". You can see it in the middle of the top bar. You have to chage it to "Global".